# How to copy 64 bits to certain address? in C

Tags: c, memcpy

I would like to copy 64 bits of variable message length and insert them at the last 64 bits of an array (`uint8_t block[64]`). I think that number `3` is stored in memory as `0000 ... 011` (64 bits total) so if I insert 64 bits of this variable into last 64 bits of `uint8_t block[64]`, number `3` should be in `block[63]`.

```
size_t length = 3;
uint64_t message_length = (uint64_t)length;
uint8_t block[64] = {0};
memcpy(&block[56], &message_length, 8);
```

Tried to achieve that with this code but unfortunately it doesn't work this way and number `3` is in `block[56]`.

Comment: "number 3 is in block[56]" -- entirely reasonable for a little-endian machine

Comment: 3 is stored in memory as 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 or 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 depending on which type of processor you have (hint: it's the first one because nobody uses the second type any more)

Comment: "I think that number 3 is stored in memory as ...."  This is incorrect.  Numbers are stored differently on different architectures, so however you think the number is stored, you are wrong (on some machines).

Answer (score 2):

If it's an endianess issue as suggested by @harold comment, then the proper way to write the value in big endian would be:

```
size_t length = 3
uint64_t message_length = length
uint8_t block[64] = { 0 };

block[56] = message_length >> 56;
block[57] = message_length >> 48;
block[58] = message_length >> 40;
block[59] = message_length >> 32;
block[60] = message_length >> 24;
block[61] = message_length >> 16;
block[62] = message_length >> 8;
block[63] = message_length >> 0;
```

Comment: Correct except for `uint8_t block[64] = {};` which uses an empty initializer, which is not allowed by the C Standard but supported as an extension.

Comment: I'm from the future, I'm using C23 standard revision. Will fix :)

Comment: Chute! I missed that one... I was using **n2595**, is **n2731** the latest draft?

Comment: Yes, and yes !.